# Java program. Adding Matrices

Tags: java

So in my code, I am supposed to add together two matrix objects using this notation `m1.add(m2)` where `m1` is and `m2` are `objects` and `add is the method` being invoked. This is what my code looks like right now. I have one constructor that generates a matrix when an object in the main method is created. Whenever I try to run the program in the main method, it gives me an error. I have to essentially take a matrix object and add it with another matrix object. Note the matrix object is created and run through the constructor first.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class matrix {
    int row;
    int column;
    static int[][] matrix;

    matrix(int row, int column) {

        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
        if (row < 1 || column < 1) {
            this.row = 1;
            this.column = 1;
        }
        if (row > 5 || column > 5) {
            this.row = 5;
            this.column = 5;
        }
        this.matrix = new int[this.row][this.column];
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 21) - 10;
            }
        }
        toString(matrix);
    }

    public static void toString(int[][] matrix2) {
        // for loop and prints each indexed variable using the system.out.print
        // method.
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix2.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("\n");
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix2[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%5d", matrix2[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");

        }


    }
       public static void add( int[][] B)
    {
       int[][]sumMatrix = new int[matrix.length][B[0].length];

       for(int i =0; i < matrix.length; i++)
      {
      for(int j=0; j < matrix[i].length;j++)
      {
         sumMatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] + B[i][j]; 
      }
    }

       toString(sumMatrix);
    }
```

Comment: You could make it easier for us by telling us what the error is. Some proper code formatting and java naming conventions wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: By reading your requirements, the main logical inconsistency I see is that your `add` method takes an `array` as its argument, but it should take a `matrix` object as its argument.

Comment: the error is the method add(int[][]) in the type matrix is not applicable for the arguments (matrix)

Comment: @Kon whenever i add matrix as the argument i get this error syntax error, insert "... VariableDeclaratorId" to complete FormalParameterList